# Aestan Tray Menu "could not execute menu item (internal error)"

Tags: wamp

I get [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb50F.png) when I try running WAMP:

> Could not execute menu item (internal error)
>   [Exception] Could not execute run action:
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

It stops me from opening WAMP. I went into Command Prompt and I typed `iisreset /stop` and I think that caused this error to happen. I tried `iisreset /start` but it says it failed to start. How can I fix this?

Comment: Restart wamp...

Comment: I think this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377255/wampserver-3-0-4-on-windows-10-64-bit-apache-server-httpd-service-did-not-s/39377626#39377626

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I reinstalled wamp to solve the issue. This may help you [reinstall wamp without losing data](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606)